# Create "part dynamic" MailChimp campaign

Tags: mailchimp

Is it possible to create a mail campaign which would be consisting of two parts? I mean I'd like to create a mailing of this kind:

1. Some hand-edited content.
2. Additional data fetched from a specific site—preferably by restAPI but I can also prepare some RSS for that if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some kind of solution to this problem. It is possible to add some content from RSS feed in regular html campaign using some called [merga tags](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/all-the-merge-tags-cheatsheet/) (look for Feed merge tags in text) so if you are able to prepare a custom rss feed on your site the job is quite simple.